# java tomcat: what library should i use to convert images to jpg and create thumbnails on-the-fly?

Tags: servlets, image-manipulation, tomcat6

I have a form that accepts image file, i want to be able to convert this image from any common format to jpg and to create a thumbnail. what's the recommended method to achieve such a thing?

Working with latest apache-tomcat on a gentoo linux server.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagemagick is a pretty solid library that a lot of people use for such a purpose.

Comment: checking out jmagick, the java implementation of imagemagick. thanks